# Getting order details as array

Tags: magento2, shipping, cart-items

I am creating a custom **shipping module**.So,I want to get the **weight** of order items individually to create shipping rule.How can we get the weight?

Comment: are you need in collectRates function or order object?

Comment: can you please share your custom code in question?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to get "cartQuote" then find out all cartQuote items. and fetch one by one item and get weight of product and create rule as per your condition

```
 $items=$cartQuote->getAllItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the result as follows...

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$weight = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;        
}

echo $weight;
```